# Generalization case vs Particular case

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing, close-reasons, re-open

Could the - generalization of a problem - post be a good enough reason in order to vote for closing
a question? I agree that in some cases is proving to be useful and the effort is significantly  reduced since we avoid giving answers to all infinitely many particular cases of a problem.  How about the following situation:

What if the generalization of a problem uses a more advanced knowledge and the question itself that is a particular case obtained from the generalization case
might be solved by using a simpler way? Some students require an answer that uses knowledge  in high school or college that is not so advanced.  [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246739/compute-int-alpha-beta-fracx-sqrtx-alpha-beta-x-dx) is one example of such a situation.
I also noticed that some people are annoyed when specifying that for a certain question is required a solution that uses high school knowledge. Why? Personally, I think that the questions
should also contain "a proof level requirement" that could be high school level, college level, university level, and it can be done more detailed. This is my first post on META! :)

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Chris'ssister: Since meta votes do not affect rep, downvotes for Meta proposals with "yes/no" components (such as feature requests) indicate a vote against.

Comment: @WillieWong: I see. OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the abstract: yes, the community has discussed this before and decided that "abstract duplication" can be a sufficient reason for closure. That is in fact why we maintain [this list of frequently asked questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions).

In the specific case: yes, it is true that this particular question can be solved more easily in the specific case, and the closure may be unwarranted. That is why we have [this thread explicitly to request reopen votes](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes). For future reference, one of the first things to do when you disagree with the closure of a question is to add an answer to the above thread (explaining why you disagree with the closure), and provide a link to that answer in the comments section of the closed question. (Since you have 3K+, you can also add a vote to re-open to the question.)